# Canot instantiate boto3 S3Transfer class

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Trying to set up boto3 S3Transfer according to AWS docs:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-1')
transfer = S3Transfer(client)
```

Result:

```
NameError: name 'S3Transfer' is not defined
```

Tried Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1 (MacOS), same result. boto3 is installed and properly resolves in my IDE (IntelliJ):

```
Successfully installed boto3-1.2.3 botocore-1.3.26 docutils-0.12 futures-3.0.5 jmespath-0.9.0 python-dateutil-2.4.2
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks, Ron

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `S3Transfer` class is in the module `boto3.s3.transfer` so you have to do something like this:

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
transfer = S3Transfer(client)
```

Note the import statement above.  Also note that the S3Transfer methods are already integrated into the S3 client and S3 resource so you may not need to access it directly.